# I flagged a question as duplicate. How can I reverse this decision?

Tags: support

The questioner added a comment and it became clear that the question is not a duplicate. How can I remove my own flag?

I deleted the comment saying that the question may be a duplicate. However, when I go to the flagging menu, the info is not gone.

Is it possible that I (with a reputation of 998) do not have access to the close  dialog to change my decision? What can I do?